# How do reference a div to a separate html without using "src?"?

Tags: html

You obviously can't make write it as:

```
<div id="left" src="left.html"></div>
```

so how would you do it?

Comment: use ajax request to load the content or use a frame

Comment: either 1. use ajax to load in content 2. use an iframe 3. use a server sided language/script to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery (complete code required below but you probably want to put jQuery in your html document head:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="left"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#left').load("left.html");
});
</script>
```

If you have php and would prefer something server side:

```
<div id="left"><?php include("left.html"); ?></div>
```

or iframe as others have suggested (but honestly this would be the worst solution IMHO

Comment: this code `$('#left').load("left.html");` should come in the `$(document).ready();` block

Comment: @zzlalani good point - the code I posted would probably work in the vast majority of cases but I agree it would be best to wait until the dom is ready.

Answer (score 0):

use an ajax request and set the innerHTML property of the `<div>` to that html data. Recommend Jquery for this.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"demo_test.html",success:function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
  }});
});
```

to load the contents of the file `demo_test.html` to the div `div1` on click of a button.

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: @user2617514 `$('#left').load('link.html')` in its simplest form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<iframe></iframe>` for insert html:

```
<iframe src="link.html" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```